# How to use a onMouseOver event in react to remove a specific index from displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Im trying to get the functionality of two es6 arrow functions to change a specific elements attributes within a react app. The element(s) im trying to change are the ***button*** elements that are built by the .map loop. When the buttons are created they have a ionic(framework) icon that looks like a play button and a number(associated) with the buttons song. The change im attempting to implement is; when I hover over the name of a song - the associated button to the left of this song needs to only display the 'play' button and the number of the song needs to be removed.

I've actually got this code about 90% working with the 'onMouseOver' and 'onMouseOut' events firing at the appropriate time and the play button displaying play as it should. Ive even been able to remove the song number as I requested above however the functionality of the appropriate song number being removed based on which song is hovered over is not working correctly.

Below are the links to the github file in question and the line numbers to the two functions I built in an attempt to accomplish this task;

[GITHUB file](https://github.com/DravionV/react-jams/blob/master/src/components/Album.js)

- Line 103(hoverOn method)
- Line 111(hoverOff method)
- Line 147(table division with event listeners)
- Line 143(built view of interior of button)

I believe the issue it that 'song' on line 143 is not changed or selected when an onMouse event occurs - therefore the first song(which is selected by default) is the only song that has its number disappear when the onMouse events fire.

Comment: I have to answers to your problem :

 1. I do not suggest doing this with javascript, since it can easily
    be done with CSS alone
 2. Make a Song component, and handle the hover state inside it

Comment: As @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI said, you can solve this with CSS.  You're already most of the way there.  Instead of conditionally rendering the number inline (line: 143), just append a different `className` to the parent, then use CSS to hide the number when the active/hovered class is present.  Alternatively, wrap a span around the number and append the active/hover class to that for targeting through CSS.

Comment: How can a 'td' element  with css :hover remove 1 specific number from the button left of it?